# conditionally add elements to jquery array from partialview

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am loading one of several partialviews depending on a selection that's made.  Inside those partial views I need to capture all of the form elements that are included on that partialview inside a jquery array.

currently I'm using this:

```
var allInputs = $('input[data-var]').add('select[data-var]').add('textarea[data-var]');
```

but that also captures all of the form elements from the parent view.  Is there a way to narrow the scope to only grab the elements on "this" partial view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your partial view rendered within a specific element?  If not, you could modify the partial view to wrap all elements and then scope your jQuery selector to that element:

Partial View:

```
<div id="myPartialView">
    <!-- inputs here .... -->
</div>
```

Then, your javascript would be as follows:

```
var allInputs = $('input[data-var]').add('select[data-var]', '#myPartialView').add('textarea[data-var]', '#myPartialView');
```

Take a look at the jQuery docs for more on selector context: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1